# XP_CMDSHELL To run a SSIS Package w/ Parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will allow me to pass in parameters to a SSIS Package.

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(200),
@ExcelPath VARCHAR(50),
@DB VARCHAR(100), 
@ExcelSheet VARCHAR(500),
@Cmd VARCHAR(4000),
@ReturnCode INT,
@Msg VARCHAR(1000),
@SQLServer varchar(255),
@EmailAddress varchar(255),
@DTEXEC varchar(255)


SELECT @Path = 'C:\SpyderNetwork Production\SSIS\IMPORTSC\'
SELECT @ExcelPath = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SR\test.xlsx' 
SELECT @ExcelSheet = 'DATA$'
select @DTEXEC = 'C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe'



exec xp_cmdshell ''

SELECT @Cmd = @DTEXEC + ' /FILE "' + @Path + 'package.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT 1 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW'
+ ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::ExcelPath].Properties[Value];' + @ExcelPath 
+ ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::ExcelSheet].Properties[Value];' + @ExcelSheet


EXEC @ReturnCode = xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```

I've replaced the parameters with their values, ran inside command prompt and everything worked, but when I implement it here I receive the following error. Again this doesn't make sense that it says I do not have permissions to run this when I can run in the command prompt and it has no problems. Am I missing something basic here?

Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 12.0.2430.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
NULL
Started:  11:29:04 AM
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:04.92
   Code: 0xC0016016
   Source: Package 
   Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that
 the correct key is available.
End Error
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:04.92
   Code: 0xC0016016
   Source: Package 
   Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that
 the correct key is available.
End Error
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0xC0202009
   Source: Package Connection manager "TEST.SpyderDB.TESTUSER"
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'TESTUSER'.".
End Error
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0xC020801C
   Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination [69]
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "TEST.SpyderDB.TESTUSER" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted bef
ore this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
End Error
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0xC0047017
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: OLE DB Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
End Error
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0xC004700C
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: One or more component failed validation.
End Error
Error: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Data Flow Task 
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
Warning: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: importSCSoldUnits 
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specifie
d in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
Warning: 2016-09-23 11:29:05.03
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: Package 
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specifie
d in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  11:29:04 AM
Finished: 11:29:05 AM
Elapsed:  0.172 seconds
NULL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248560/sql-server-jobs-with-ssis-packages-failed-to-decrypt-protected-xml-node-dtsp

I would check this out.

Comment: Yep, that was the solution. Created SSIS Package ProtectionLevel property to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword & The Project Protection Level to be the same. Added /De Password (Same as the passwords used in the protection level) to the SQL to execute the SSIS. Everything is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2012 or Higher, there are other solutions available without using the xp_cmdshell.

The projects should be in project deployment model and deployed to SSISDB catalog.

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
        @folder_name = N'Folder',
        @project_name = N'Test',
        @package_name = N'Package.dtsx',
        @reference_id = NULL,
        @use32bitruntime = FALSE,     
        @execution_id = @executionID OUTPUT

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @executionID,
    @object_type = 20, 
    @parameter_name = N'Var1', 
    @parameter_value = @Var1

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @executionID,
    @object_type = 20, 
    @parameter_name = N'Var2', 
    @parameter_value = @Var2

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @executionID
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have to give this a try. This is much cleaner than what I was attempting.